# Undefined variable: listado

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Mi problema es que no enlista un reporte de pagos en DataTable con información proveniente de una consulta AJAX, me marcar el error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: listado in C:\xampp\htdocs\pb\listar_pagos.php on line 28
null
```

Lo raro es que con algunos usuarios del sistema si enlista los registros e ignora el error antes mencionado, les dejo mi código de listar_pagos.php

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    include ("database/database.php");
    $registroAgente = $_SESSION['usuario_pb'];
    $stmt_mysql = "SELECT * FROM pagos WHERE registroAgente = '$registroAgente' ORDER BY 
    fechaPago DESC";
    $t_mysql = mysqli_query($mysql_conexion_pb, $stmt_mysql);
    if(!$t_mysql) {
        die("ERROR");
    } else {
        while($pagos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($t_mysql)) {
            $listado["data"][] = $pagos;
        }
        echo json_encode($listado);
    }
    mysqli_free_result($t_mysql);
    mysqli_close($mysql_conexion_pb);
 ?>
```

Por un momento pense que era el free_result pero no, ya le hice un logger y me da el error mencionado de al principio, con eso que algunos usuario si enlista y a otro no, me hace pensar que es la base de datos de donde proviene el error, cuando tiro el query directo en Workbench me indica

```
Error Code: 1046. No database selected Select the default DB to be used by double-clicking its 
name in the SCHEMAS list in the sidebar.
```

Reviso el fichero con mi conexión pero me indica que si tengo la conexión correcta, me da espina que a tengo que poner a que base y tabla consultar, pero igual me marca error, tambien estuve revisándolo con POSTMAN

Comment: Tienes que declarar la variable $listado desde antes para que sea evaluada. No solo dentro del while.

Comment: Podrías poner el fragmento de código ¡Porfavor!